# How can i pause and play gif which is set on webpage background

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code :

```
enter code here
        <style type="text/css">
        body  
          {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-image:url(AU.gif) ;
            border-image-repeat: no-repeat;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            margin: 60px 450px;
            background-position: center center;
            background-size: cover;
        }
       body>.grid 
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        .image 
        {
            margin-top: -100px;
        }
        
        .column     
        {
            max-width: 450px;
        }
```

Output :

[enter image description here][1]

------ this is GIF of my webpage ------
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GflkC.gif

Now , I want to do umm when any user open this webpage then the GIF aniamation stop at that GIF first state(which is we can see all kind of lines and Dots) and pause there in current position after user enter write login creds then this GIF animation continue and go to its last state (which is we can see GIF animation become invisible). So that kind of any css attribute or JS code possible or not ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: there's no way to control a gif like that. you can try to time it and replace with static image or have the gif stop how you want it to look and stay; they don't have to repeat.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to pause and play a gif, but it is possible when there is a video instead of a gif using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

stop and pause gif you can only by changing source from .gif to .img or .jpeg and so on. There is no special function for it. Also you can create this function on your own

Comment: The last part of your answer was informative and good (creating a own function) but changing the source is not a nice way to go, because you can't stop gif's at all, you would just manipulate the source at the time.